# Escaping special symbols in Sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file

I have a bat file which executes bunch of sql scripts when i install my application. In installation dialogs user sets dbname, login and password which are then used in this bat file. Here it is:

```
SET _server="(local)"
SET _db=dbname
SET _user=sa
SET _pswr="!#$%^&*()<>"

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe -S %_server% -d %_db% -U %_user% -P %_pswr% -A all

"%systemdrive%\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.exe" -S %_server% -d %_db% -U %_user% -P %_pswr% -i .\createDB.sql

pause
```

Everything works great until password doesn't contain any special symbols. But if it does i get following error "Login failed for user 'sa'.". So it's obvious, that somethins wrong with password. And now the question: How can i escape these special symbols in bat file?

PS: 
I tried replacing:

```
< - &lt;
> - &gt;
& - &amp;
```

But it doesn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: There are several issues with DOS batch scripting. Running the query from a command line you can use the % character without issue. Placing the code inside a batch file, without calling other batch files, then you double the character, i.e. %%. If you have to call another batch script within that batch script you can get away with just %%. If you need to call it within a loop then, to allow the control of flow to continue, you need to use the CALL operator to start the nested batch. When doing so you need to double the characters, i.e. %%%%. I'm assuming that the scripting layer performs a cou

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the percent (%) character and the caret(^) character by doubling them. Here is a [list](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) of problematic command line characters

```
SET _pswr="!#$%%^^&*()<>"
```

Comment: That's why I provided the link, I'm bound to forget some weird character :)

Comment: Thanks for response. After few experiments i found that following characters can be used in batch file - "!#$%^*&()<>!@:?=-`~+/[]|". And i need to escape only one of them (% - %%). But symbols "; № " '  \" causes errors. I also tried to use rules from that link you gave me, but none of them worked. So maybe there are other ways to escape them?

Comment: Escaping in the console is usually done either by a backslash (\), by a caret (^) or by doubling the character. If none of those work, I'm not sure what to do, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Tested as well with windows batch file on Windows 2008 Server SP2 with sqlcmd. Only needed to escape the % sign as %%. No need to escape the ^.

Comment: Thanks to SWeko for initial answer. Hopes this answer helps someone else down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge today with using [SQL Agent Job Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps?view=sql-server-ver16) together with sqlcmd for deployment, in particular [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps). This has a conflict as the Tokens are interpreted as [sqlcmdvars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-use-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-ver16).

The way in which I got around this was to escape the sqlcmdvar declaration by escaping the dollar symbol as shown in the below sql script. Together with this I declared and set sqlcmdvar variable with the declaration of the Token itself (minus the dollar sign).
This allowed me to call the SQL Agent Job script via sqlcmd and still have it preserve the Token declaration within the step declaration.

```
    declare @Job_name varchar(200)
    ,@Step_name varchar(200)

set @Job_name  = '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBNAME))'
set @Step_name = '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPNAME))'

print 'The is example print statement!'
print 'The is example '+@Job_name 
print 'The is example '+@Step_name
```

The sql script contain the sql agent job declaration: "example sql agent job with tokens.sql"

```
:setvar JOBNAME (ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBNAME))
:setvar STEPNAME (ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPNAME))

USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [ExampleJob]    Script Date: 23/10/2023 13:27:48 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]    Script Date: 23/10/2023 13:27:48 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'ExampleJob', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'This is just an example to show how to Tokens alongside SQLCMDVARs.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'*****', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [Example Step]    Script Date: 23/10/2023 13:27:49 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Example Step', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'declare @Job_name varchar(200)
    ,@Step_name varchar(200)

set @Job_name  = ''$$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBNAME))''
set @Step_name = ''$$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPNAME))''

print ''The is example print statement!''
print ''The is example ''+@Job_name 
print ''The is example ''+@Step_name', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=4
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Example Schedule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=2, 
        @freq_subday_interval=10, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20231023, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'8400e289-6b41-47fd-8692-ad7e74fd7146'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO
```

The powershell script calling the above sql script:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\Users\{user}\Downloads\example sql agent job with tokens.sql" -ServerInstance "(local)"
```

***Please remember to replace the {user} within the path mentioned above with your local filepath.
Also remember to replace the owner_login_name value with something valid for your SQL instance.*