# sqlcmd access : password with special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, special-characters, sqlcmd

i try to access with sqlcmd by this command:

sqlcmd  -U sa -P $test$ -S hostname -d db_test -i .\prova.sql > upgrade.log

but the login failed.

The password i correct, i think is a problem with special character, in this case the $.

Do yuo have any solutions?

Thanks
F.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping special symbols in Sqlcmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041145/escaping-special-symbols-in-sqlcmd)

Comment: Please provide the version of SQL Server you are connecting to via this command line. On 2014 it works: sqlcmd -U sa1 -P $password$ -S VMDBSRVDEMO001\SQLEXPRESS2014 -d itest -i .\prova.sql > upgrade.log

Comment: i use sql 2005,2008 and 2012, not 2014.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as fabrix_00, the sqlcmd I'm using is the sqlcmd (go) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=go%2Clinux&pivots=cs1-bash#find-out-which-version-you-have-installed

Answer (score 3):

the solution is use the "", in this case:

-P "$test"

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Also your password seems to be missing the second $ in this example.

Comment: Did't work with the recent sqlcmd (go) as of 1.5.0-1~buster

Answer (score -1):

Pop a -x at the start of your sqlCMD and them for the password use double quote marks after the P.

EG -

sqlcmd -x  -U sa -P "$test$" -S hostname -d db_test -i .\prova.sql > upgrade.log